# Multiple rolling mean across same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the data set which I am trying to find the multiple rolling means with interval 2,4,6,8for the same data frame appended below

Dataset:

```
d = {'Key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 'col1': [15000, 12000, 6000, 7000], 'col2': [15000, 10000, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

[image]

I am looking to have multiple rolling means appended below to initial data frame-df
[image]

This is an example of having rolling 2 and 4 and we can distinguish it by the first column "Rolling_mean".

Comment: Question is unclear , please adding more detail

Comment: Thanks I cleaned it up

Comment: Updated ~,let me know if this is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the update

```
n = [2,4,6,8]
out = pd.concat([df.assign(average=df.rolling(x)['col2'].mean()) for x in n ] , keys = n).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0':'Rolling_mean'})
Out[178]: 
   Rolling_mean Key   col1   col2  average
0             2   A  15000  15000      NaN
1             2   B  12000  10000  12500.0
2             2   C   6000      0   5000.0
3             2   D   7000      0      0.0
0             4   A  15000  15000      NaN
1             4   B  12000  10000      NaN
2             4   C   6000      0      NaN
3             4   D   7000      0   6250.0
0             6   A  15000  15000      NaN
1             6   B  12000  10000      NaN
2             6   C   6000      0      NaN
3             6   D   7000      0      NaN
0             8   A  15000  15000      NaN
1             8   B  12000  10000      NaN
2             8   C   6000      0      NaN
3             8   D   7000      0      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, "Rolling_mean" is the new column that should be created, so I cannot apply group by.If you look closely there are only 4 records and 3 columns in the initial dataset and for each rolling the new df gets appended to the bottom and creates two new columns("Rolling_mean", Rolling average)

Comment: @HKE check the update , you question is little bit confused ~